# How to store Large input text Value from html to servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

```
    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Coupon Description---Max word limit 500" rows="3"></textarea>
```

How to save this textarea in an Array or in some other data type field which can store large number of text?

```
    String [] couponDesc=request.getParameter("description");//This code is not working
```

Comment: Your left side variable is array, but you are returning string, Fix that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.getParameter(String);` method returns a String and not an array of Strings. There is no restriction in the servlet specification about the data returned from a request parameter. Just assign your parameter data to a String.

```
String couponDesc=request.getParameter("description");
```

This will load all the data in your text area into the `couponDesc` variable.

> **Update**

Also, in your html textarea tag, add the max length attribute like so:

`<textarea class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Coupon Description---Max word limit 500" rows="3" maxlength="500"></textarea>`

Then in your database column, have the column length set to 500. This should ensure that the data input by the user can easily fit your database requirements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i cannot store large text values in database by this String couponDesc=request.getParameter("description");;

Comment: That seems to be a problem with the database column. You will need to either change the database column OR parse your data from the servlet and then break the data and then store it in the database.

Comment: kindly tell me how to store it

Comment: Thank you.its working now with string  by Setting the database column to LongText from Varchar